# Error: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class UsersFreeze_batch_Test{

        static final String COMP = 'HID Global';

        static final list<Countries__c> COUNTRIES = new list<Countries__c>([SELECT Name, Country__c, Region__c, Territory__c FROM Countries__c]);
        static final list<States__c> STATES = new list<States__c>([SELECT Name, State__c, Region__c, Territory__c FROM States__c]);

        static User u;

        static {
            Profile p = [
                SELECT
                Id
                FROM
                Profile
                WHERE
                Name = 'HID Sales User - IAM'
            ];
            u = new User(
                Alias = 'u1',
                Email = 'u1@hidglobal.com',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LastName = 'Testing',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                ProfileId = p.Id,
                Country = 'United States',
                CountryCode = 'US',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                Username = 'u1@hidglobal.com',
                Frozen__c = true
            );
            insert u; 

        }
     static User u1;

        static {
            Profile p = [
                SELECT
                Id
                FROM
                Profile
                WHERE
                Name = 'HID Sales User - IAM'
            ];
            u1 = new User(
                Alias = 'u2',
                Email = 'u2@hidglobal.com',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LastName = 'Testing1',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                ProfileId = p.Id,
                Country = 'United States',
                CountryCode = 'US',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                Username = 'u2@hidglobal.com',
                Frozen__c = true
            );
            insert u1; 

        }


        static testMethod void testBatch(){
            test.startTest();
            UsersUnFreeze_batch obj01 = new UsersUnFreeze_batch();
            Database.executeBatch(obj01,1);
            test.stopTest();
        }
}
```

Apex Class:::::

```
global class UsersFreeze_batch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {

// "Start" runs when the class in instanciated
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bcMain) {

if(test.IsRunningTest()){
return Database.getQueryLocator([select isFrozen,userId,id from UserLogin where isFrozen =:false limit 1]);
}
return Database.getQueryLocator([select isFrozen,userId,id from UserLogin where isFrozen =:false]);
}

public void FreezeUsers(List<UserLogin> lstUserData){

        if(Label.Freeze_Escape_Profiles != null){
        List<String> escapeProfiles = Label.Freeze_Escape_Profiles.split(',');
        set<String> setEscapeProfiles = new set<string>();
        setEscapeProfiles.addall(escapeProfiles);

        if(!lstUserData.IsEmpty()){
        List<UserLogin> recordsToProcess = new List<UserLogin>();
        List<User> usersToUpdate = new List<User>();

            set<Id> userIds = new set<Id>();
            for(UserLogin ul:lstUserData){

                userIds.add(ul.userId);
            }

            Map<Id,User> mapUsers = new Map<Id,User>([select id,name from user where Profile.Name Not In:setEscapeProfiles and Id In:userIds and IsActive=:true]);

             for(UserLogin uls:lstUserData){

                 if(mapUsers.containsKey(uls.UserId)){
                     uls.IsFrozen = true;
                     recordsToProcess.add(uls);

                     user u = new user();
                     u.Id = uls.UserId;
                     u.Frozen__c = true;
                     usersToUpdate.add(u);
                 }
             }

             if(!usersToUpdate.IsEmpty()){

                 update usersToUpdate;
             }


             if(!recordsToProcess.IsEmpty()){

                 update recordsToProcess;
             }
        }
        }

}


global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bcMain, List<SObject> lstBatchRecords) 
{
   FreezeUsers(lstBatchRecords);
}


// Finish the Batch Job
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        List<AsyncApexJob> lsta = [Select Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,
        TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email, ExtendedStatus
        from AsyncApexJob where Status =: 'Failed'];        

        if(!lsta.IsEmpty()){
        AsyncApexJob a = lsta[0];
        string plainbody = 'The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems+' batches with '+a.NumberOfErrors+ ' failures. ExtendedStatus: ' + a.ExtendedStatus;
        sendEmai(a.Status,a.CreatedBy.Email,'Users Freeze Status: ',plainbody );
        }else{
        string plainbody = 'All the Users are Successfully Freezed, except System Admins and HID Integrations';
        sendEmai('Success',userinfo.getuserEmail(),'Users Freeze Status: ',plainbody );

        }
    }

    global void sendEmai(string status,string email,string subject,string plainbody ){

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        // Send the email to the job submitter
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Batch Processing');
        mail.setSubject(subject+' ' + status);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(plainbody);

        // Add your attachment to the email.
        if(!test.IsRunningTest()) {
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem in my test class which is covering one batch class which is running on user.

The problem is when you are running a test class only one time execute method should execute.

So when you are executing the batch class. please increase the batch size like below code.

```
 static testMethod void testBatch(){
        test.startTest();
        UsersUnFreeze_batch obj01 = new UsersUnFreeze_batch();
        Database.executeBatch(obj01,300);
        test.stopTest();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro